# How to implement group by without collapsing data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simplified my query, so now it looks like below:

```
SELECT allaccounts.*, groups.TOTALGROUPAMOUNT
FROM 
(**SELECT FROM DUMMYTABLE WHERE...**) allaccounts,
(SELECT groupID, SUM(memberAmount) totalGroupAmount FROM(**SELECT FROM DUMMYTABLE WHERE...**) group by groupID) groups
WHERE allaccounts.groupID = groups.groupID
```

Where SELECT FROM DUMMYTABLE WHERE... looks like:

```
GROUP|ACCOUNT|BALANCE
A    |101    |1000
A    |102    |2000
A    |103    |3000
B    |104    |4000
B    |105    |5000
C    |106    |6000
```

And with query above I'm expecting below result:

```
GROUP|ACCOUNT|BALANCE|TOTALGROUPAMOUNT
A    |101    |1000   |6000
A    |102    |2000   |6000
A    |103    |3000   |6000
B    |104    |4000   |9000
B    |105    |5000   |9000
C    |106    |6000   |6000
```

So my question is it possible to make grouping not using "**SELECT FROM DUMMYTABLE WHERE...**" twice?

Thanks for your answers and advises in advance!

Comment: What you're after are [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). Very useful and powerful, if used in the right context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum() over()`.

```
select t.*, sum(balance) over(partition by grp) totalgroupamount
from tablename t
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  It is exactly what I have been looking for!